# Regarding Login form creation in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

i have created a simple login form on which by giving username and password it traverses to next page and shows the username and password..
But my problem is both username and password is not displayed in the next page.only one is displayed at a time..
as I'm new to android could anyone please help me out of this..

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String UN = "com.example.loginpage.USERNAME";
    public static final String PWD = "com.example.loginpage.PASSWORD";

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText EditText01 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        EditText EditText02 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText02);
        String Un = EditText01.getText().toString();
        String Pwd = EditText02.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(UN, Un);
        intent.putExtra(PWD, Pwd);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

and My next Activity code is(DisplayMessageActivity)

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
     getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
     Intent intent = getIntent();
     String message1 = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.UN);
     String message2 = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.PWD);
     TextView textView1 = new TextView(this);
     textView1.setTextSize(40);
     textView1.setText(message1);
     TextView textView2 = new TextView(this);
     textView2.setTextSize(40);
     textView2.setText(message2);
     setContentView(textView1);
     setContentView(textView2);
 }
```

i want to display both USername and Password in the next page
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `setContentView()` replace previous layout you set before. Try to use `addContentView()` instead. Or even better way would be to define these text views in layout file show_login_and_password.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and then onCreate in your activity

```
setContentView(R.layout.show_login_and_password);

TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
t1.setText(intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.UN));

TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview2);
t2.setText(intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.PWD));
```

Comment: can u explain me more clearly??whether i have to replace all the code from activity_main.xml or txtview alone??

Comment: `setContentView()` used by activity to set layout. You can create as many layouts as you want. So since you have 2 activities it would be handy to have 2 layouts predefined in xml: activity_main.xml - for your main activity to enter login and password and activity_show_login_and_password.xml - to show given login and password.

After you set content view in `onCreate()` method, you can retrieve any element this layout contains by its id and then use it as you want.

Comment: I got it right thatnks for ur beautiful explanation..i missed a code while tryig first time..thanks soo soo much..it was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView textView1=new TextView(this);
textView1.setTextSize(40);
textView1.setText(message1);
TextView textView2=new TextView(this);
textView2.setTextSize(40);
textView2.setText(message2);
setContentView(textView1);
setContentView(textView2);
```

The way you set your textview it wont show up. How about adding those textviews in your activity_display_message layout xml?

First create your activity_display_message.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Change your onCreate() method like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
     getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
     Intent intent = getIntent();
     String message1 = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.UN);
     String message2 = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.PWD);
     TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
     textView1.setTextSize(40);
     textView1.setText(message1);
     TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview2);
     textView2.setTextSize(40);
     textView2.setText(message2);
 }
```

Comment: can u please explain in detail??how to do this

Comment: Ok post your activity_display_message.xml first>

Answer (score 0):

this is your problem:

```
setContentView(textView1);
setContentView(textView2);
```

the second call overwrites the first one.

Define a layout in XML and put your values into the already defined textboxes/labels

Comment: how can we do this??can u pls explain in more detail

Comment: please read this manual: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

also refer to Sean John's answer for your case. He made a clear example I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
return extras != null ? extras.getString(MainActivity.UN) : "nothing passed in";
```

Answer (score 0):

My goodness How you can write setContentView two times.

Here is corrected snippet.

```
// Creating a new LinearLayout
LinearLayout parentLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

// Setting the orientation to vertical
parentLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

final TextView txtName = new TextView(this);
final TextView txtPwd = new TextView(this);

txtName.setText(message1);
txtPwd.setText(message2);

// Defining the layout parameters of the TextView
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

txtName.setLayoutParams(lp);
txtPwd.setLayoutParams(lp);


parentLayout.addView(txtName);
parentLayout.addView(txtPwd);

setContentView(parentLayout, llp);
```